# Cannot Set An Array From Google Web App To Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to combine a new value to an existing value in Google Sheet. So when user input the codeInput then it will find the codeInput row and add formObject.things value that user just filled to the existing thingsList value (which the same row as codeInput). I tried this code but it return blank to the Google Sheet.

Your response would be very appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
function update1(formObject) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
      
    var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
    var thingsList = data.map(function(r){return r[8]; });
    var position = codeList.indexOf(formObject.codeInput);
    var array = [thingsList[position], formObject.things]

    if (position > -1) {
        position += 5;
        ws.getRange(position,9).setValue(array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding

```
var array = [thingsList[position], formObject.things]
```

and

```
 ws.getRange(position,9).setValue(array);
```

1. The type of `array` is `Array`
2. `setValue` doesn't allow `Array` objects as argument. It accepts, `string`, `number`, `Date` and `Boolean`

Instead of `setValue`

1. you could pass a Google Sheets *array* (i.e. `={1,2}`) by using `setFormula`
2. you could pass a bidimenstional `Array` to Google Sheets by using `setValues`
3. you could pass an array (unidimensional `Array`) by using `appendRow`

---

Regarding

```
var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
```

and

```
var thingsList = data.map(function(r){return r[8]; });
```

`data` is and `Array` possible having multiple *rows* but it has only one *column*, so, `r[8]` returns `null` which cause that `thinkslist` be an array of `null` values.

So far the question doesn't include enough details to know what could be the fix needed, but here are two possibilities among others :

```
var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 9).getValues();
```

or

```
var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```